# How to move multiple UITableView rows using Drag & Drop on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, uitableview, drag-and-drop

On iOS 11 it's very easy to move one UITableView row to another index path with drag and drop. But I couldn't find a way to move multiple rows with drag and drop. I've implemented all required delegate methods but UITableView view still doesn't opens up a gap for a multiple-row drop and `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator)` is never called.

Here is my implementation of `UITableViewDropDelegate` and `UITableViewDragDelegate`.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(item: nil, typeIdentifier: nil)
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)

    return [dragItem]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForAddingTo session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(item: nil, typeIdentifier: nil)
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)

    return [dragItem]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal {
    return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
    ...
}
```

Drag and drop is enabled and the delegates are set as well.

```swift
tableView.dragDelegate = self
tableView.dropDelegate = self
tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: This answer seems to say we can't https://stackoverflow.com/a/46040063/558575 - another example of Apple giving with one hand and taking back with another.

Comment: I also got a response from an UIKit engineer that this is not possible. https://twitter.com/smileyborg/status/879775985712975872

Comment: So much for Apple employing the best and brightest! "It’s significantly more difficult to do it right" - so Apple don't do it and leave it to every indy developer to work it out themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to make it work with a little bit of hackery. The trick is to remember the row selections but not actually select the rows. Here is what I did in my didSelectRow delegate callback:

```
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        guard let imageView = cell?.accessoryView as? UIImageView else { return }
        if isSelected(indexPath: indexPath) {
            imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "circle")
            removeSelected(indexPath: indexPath)
        } else {
            imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
            selectedItems.append(indexPath)
        }
```

selectedItems is a global array of IndexPaths with a few helper methods.

Now in itemsForBeginning call, I have this code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider()
    
    var dragItems: [UIDragItem] = []
    if isSelected(indexPath: indexPath) == false {
        selectedItems.append(indexPath)
    }
    for item in selectedItems {
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = item
        dragItems.append(dragItem)
    }
    return dragItems
}
```

and in performDropWith, here is what I have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
    guard let draggedItems = coordinator.session.localDragSession?.items else { return }
    guard let destinationPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath else { return }

    selectedItems = []
    for draggedItem in draggedItems {
        guard let item = draggedItem.localObject as? IndexPath  else { continue }
        // do whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected. The only annoying part is, the drag action shows count correctly, but animates only the row where the drag is initiated, not all the rows.