# Change an order of the items with long press SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a simple app, and I want to be able to change the order of items when I make a long press like in Safari with tabs. I know that I need to use `.onLongPressGesture`, but I can't implement it.

```
import SwiftUI
    
    struct HomeView: View {
        
        struct Item: Identifiable {
            var id = UUID()
            var name: String
            var color: Color
        }
        
        @State var items = [
            Item(name: "Item 1", color: .red),
            Item(name: "Item 2", color: .green),
            Item(name: "Item 3", color: .blue)
        ]
        
        var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    Text(item.name)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding()
                        .background(item.color)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
            }
        }
        
        func deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
            items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }
    
    
    struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            HomeView()
        }
    }
```

Comment: [This sample app](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/sample-apps/recognizinggestures) impliments this gesture - I think it has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.onLongPressGesture`, you can use `.onMove` to change the order of items - in iOS, long press is already a requirement for reordering when using `.onMove`.

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
            Text(item.name)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .background(item.color)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
        .onMove(perform: move)
    }
}

func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
    items.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
}
```

(Code based on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71123030/15372665))

I hope this helps.